# Redirect function has unstable behaviour

Tags: php, redirect

I have defined a function for redirecting a user as part of a login system:

```
function redirect_user($page = 'default.php') {   // default value. 

    $url='http://' .$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $url=rtrim($url, '/\\'); //remove any trailing slashes
    $url .= '/' .$page; //concat page to $url
    header("Location: $url"); //redirect user
    exit(); //quit script

} //end of redirect function
```

In the login script, after I validate login information, I successfully redirect the user to the logged in page as such:

```
redirect_user('includes/loggedin.php');
```

However I am trying to do the same thing for my registration handling script and it **does not get redirected to the login page**.

I define the function at the beginning of the script and inserted the redirect function by replacing

```
if ($r) {  //If it ran okay
    echo '<h1> Thank you!</h1><p>You are now registered</p>'; //print message
}
```

with

```
if ($r) {       //If it ran okay
    redirect_user('login.php'); //redirect user to login
}
```

I tried

```
header('location: login.php');
exit();
```

and got the same results, a blank page with the registration handling url.

The registration part of the script works and I see the information in my registration DB, but the redirect does not work like I would expect.

Comment: What do you mean 'does not work'? Does it show an error, white screen, blue screen or give any sort of indication on what is happening?

Comment: Why do you think you need all that extranious guff i.e. the function. Just use `header('Location: login.php'); exit;` whenever you want to redirect. Non of the stuff in that function is doing anything necessary its just eating CPU cycles.

Comment: The headers probably have been sent already, make sure you don't have any output before your redirect.

Comment: @jeroen Makes a good point. Look in the PHP Error log for a message saying `Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent` or something like that.

Comment: By not working, I mean I do not get redirected to the login page.  In the address bar, I see the url for the registration handling script.  I do understand the function and use of header().  As suggested, and rightly so, I defined the function so I can use the script on my local server and not worry about path issues on a remote server.  Hmmm...I could try just using the header() function.

Comment: Dont add anthing to do with the specific domain to any redirect `header()` just use relative paths and PHP does all the heavy lifting. Unless of course you want to redirect to another domain. This also makes your code completely transportable, and without any effort from you, I think this comes under the heading of `Dont reinvent the wheel`

Comment: I have an insert query before the redirect therefor the ($r).  Is that a problem?

Comment: In my research, I read somewhere (unless I misunderstood) you have to use an absolute address for "location" and not a relative address.  Do I have this wrong?

Comment: I tried just using "header('location: login.php'); exit();  and I got the same results...a blank page with my registration handling url in the address bar.  The registration part of the script works and I see the information in my registration DB.  The redirect just does not work like I would expect.

Comment: Hey there. I've tried to improve your question a bit. I edited it with some of your comments. Feel free to make corrections. I also formatted the code in a more concise way. Notice how I removed some part of your original text which were more about asking for help than your question, to keep it as straightforward as possible. Welcome to SO!